# Remove last line from a StringBuilder without knowing the number of characters

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I want to know if there exists a simple method for removing the last line from a StringBuilder object without knowing the number of characters in the last line.

Example:

> Hello, how are you?
>   Fine thanks!
>   Ok, Perfect...

I want to remove "Ok, Perfect..."

Comment: what do you mean by last line? Can you share a sample String and show which part you want to remove ?

Comment: Use `lastIndexOf(String str)` which returns the index within this string of the rightmost occurrence of the specified substring.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Hello, how are you?\nFine thanks!\nOk, Perfect...");

int last = sb.lastIndexOf("\n");
if (last >= 0) { sb.delete(last, sb.length()); }
```

http://ideone.com/9k8Tcj

**EDIT:** If you want to remove the last non-empty line do

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(
        "Hello, how are you?\nFine thanks!\nOk, Perfect...\n\n");
if (sb.length() > 0) {
    int last, prev = sb.length() - 1;
    while ((last = sb.lastIndexOf("\n", prev)) == prev) { prev = last - 1; }
    if (last >= 0) { sb.delete(last, sb.length()); }
}
```

http://ideone.com/AlzQe0

Comment: That does not remove the last line but the last `\n` (if every line ends with it)

Comment: And `\n` could be at the end or not found in the string at all.

Comment: StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Hello, how are you?\nFine thanks!\nOk, Perfect...\n"); what about this?

Comment: @Hiru, I would say the last line is empty in this case!

Comment: What about multiple trailing non-empty lines?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how your Strings are constructed and what your goal is, it may be easier to not add the last line to the `StringBuilder` instead of removing it.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your performance requirements there are a few options:

One option, as already mentioned by others, would be to look for the last index of `\n` and if it is the last character recursively look for the next to last index etc. until you hit the last non-empty line.

Another option would be to use regular expressions to look for that:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Hello, how are you?\nFine thanks!\nOk, Perfect...\n\n");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\n[^\n]+\n+$");
Matcher m= p.matcher( sb );

//if there is a last line that matches our requirements
if( m.find() ) {
  sb.delete( m.start( 0 ), m.end( 0 ) );
}
```

If you consider whitespace as empty you could change the expression to `\n[^\n]+[\s\n]+$` (as a Java string that would be `"\n[^\n]+[\\s\n]+$"`) .